# GPS: An Introduction to Satellite Navigation, with an interactive Worldwide Laboratory using Smartphones

Tags: discussion, topic-of-week

There is a Coursera course going on now that I think might be of interest to a lot of people here, that can be found at https://class.coursera.org/gpslab-001 . It talks about how GPS navigation is achieved. I'm just going to make a plug that we should all take a look, and ask relevant questions from the course if applicable. Call it a topic of the next two months or so;-)

Comment: The course is removed together with a lot of other courses. If anyone knows where to find it, could you please post a link?

Comment: Sadly there doesn't seem to be a similar class. Pity, it was an interesting course...